# Spring Kafka stream processor not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to write a Kafka stream processor using Spring boot but it's not getting invoked when messages are produced into the topic.

I have the following producer that works fine with the topic name `adt.events.location`.

```
@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "adt.events.location";
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    public Producer(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void produce() {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "1", new EventPatientCheckedIn(1L, 1001L, 104L, 11L, 6L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "1", new EventPatientBedChanged(1L, 1001L, 7L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "1", new EventPatientRoomChanged(1L, 1001L, 10L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "2", new EventPatientCheckedIn(2L, 1002L, 110L, 18L, 2L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "3", new EventPatientCheckedIn(3L, 1003L, 111L, 16L, 1L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "1", new EventPatientCheckedOut(1L, 1001L));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, "3", new EventPatientBedChanged(3L, 1003L, 3L));
    }
}
```

*The topic messages have different types and are in **Avro format**. The schema is registered in the schema registry with **Avro union**.*

These are the topics

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicEventsLocation() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("adt.events.location").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicPatientLocation() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("adt.patient.location").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
}
```

application.yml *I'm using cp-all-in-one-community as docker-file*

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      auto:
        register:
          schemas: false
      use:
        latest:
          version: true
      schema:
        registry:
          url: http://localhost:8081
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    streams:
      application-id: kafka-demo
      properties:
        default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
        default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
```

Spring Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the Processor

```
@Component
public class Processor {

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    @Autowired
    public void process() {
        ...    
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is to see the schema name printed out every time a message is produced and the output topic `adt.patient.location` being populated with the stream process output but nothing happen.

I'm new to Kafka so probably I'm missing something.

**UPDATE**

I was actually missing the `@EnableKafkaStreams` annotation.

But now I get the following error:

```
2021-04-07 16:02:16.967 ERROR 120225 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [LocationService-9611eedf-df9b-4fe5-9a7d-058027cee22a] Topology with no input topics will create no stream threads and no global thread.
2021-04-07 16:02:16.967  WARN 120225 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
```

Comment: Are you using spring cloud stream? The imperative or the functional style?

Comment: Post the configuration that you have in the `application.yml`

Comment: functional style, without spring cloud stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two errors:

1. Add the annotation `@EnableKafkaStreams`
2. Error in the processor with the `StreamsBuilder` injection

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Autowired
public void process(final StreamsBuilder builder) {
    logger.info("Processing location events");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Autowired` on the `KafkaTemplate`. I think this is the thing that you are missing. The example that I give does not use AvroSerializer. So I assume that your serializer is working. At least you should see the message arriving on the consumer or a serialization error. Moreover, you can improve your method to handle callbacks and use a more consistent message record. For instance, use the `ProducerRecord` to create the message that you will send. Add a callback using `ListenableFuture`.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Producer {
   @Autowired
   KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

   public void produce() {
        String key = "1";
        Object value = EventPatientCheckedIn....

        ProducerRecord<String, Object> producerRecord = buildProducerRecord(TOPIC, key, value);

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> listenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);

        listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) { handleFailure(key, value, ex); }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Object> result) { handleSuccess(key, value, result); }
        });
    }

    private ProducerRecord<String, Object> buildProducerRecord(String topic, String key, Object value) {
        List<Header> recordHeaders = List.of(new RecordHeader("event-source", "scanner".getBytes()));
        return new ProducerRecord<String, Object>(topic, null, key, value, recordHeaders);
    }

    private void handleSuccess(String key, Object value, SendResult<String, Object> result) {
        log.info("message send successfully for the key: {} and value: {} at partition: {}", key, value, result.getRecordMetadata().partition());
    }

    private void handleFailure(String key, Object value, Throwable ex) {
        log.error("error sending the message and the exception us {}", ex.getMessage());
        try { throw ex; }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
            log.error("error on failure: {}", throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I think you are missing to configure `Properties` and then make the `streams.start();` on your `Processor`. I based this example on [this reference](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/).

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "adt.events.location");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-broker1:9092");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, YOUR_AVRO_SERDE_HERE);
...
...
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
streams.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint on the producer side, I'll have a look in details but the problem I posted is regarding the processor that is not invoked when the messages are sent to the topic.
The current producer can be improved but it's working, I see the messages arriving into the topic.

Comment: ow, I see. then your problem is on the consumer side. did you try to use `@KafkaListener(topics = {TOPIC})` for the method `public void process() {`?

Comment: you forgot to star the stream. check my update